# cmake failed to detect gcc4.7

Tags: gcc, cmake

My system is ubuntu 12.04, defaut gcc is 4.6. I installed gcc 4.7 and use apt-alternatives command switch gcc to gcc4.7. But when using cmake code like below. I still got the "Need at least GCC 4.7" error.

```
 CHECK_C_SOURCE_COMPILES("#define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 +      __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
   #if GCC_VERSION < 40700
   #error Not GCC 4.7.0+
   #endif
   int main() { return 0; }" HAVE_GCC_47)

 if (NOT HAVE_GCC_47)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "Need at least GCC 4.7")
 endif()
```

Comment: Set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` var.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the C and/or CXX compiler on the command line, so if you have a project in src, and make a build directory next to src, then the following invocation would ensure the compiler was used (this must be passed in a clean directory, not one with an existing cache:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/path/to/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/path/to/g++ ../src
```

You can also set the environment variables CC and CXX in your shell/on the command line. They will be used, and are fairly standard in *nix environments. The page at http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables is a useful reference for CMake variables too.